# How can a DLL access an EXE class?

Tags: c++, class, methods, dll, undefined

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to modularize some components. One of these is Windowing. I'm trying to pass input back to the main EXE though, and I'm doing this through a user interface function which in turn calls the main methods in the main input system class. The latter class is far too complicated to even have a header available on both systems (depends on many classes).

Anyways, so the actual issue is that I can't access any methods in the input interface class!

```
class WINDOW_EXPORT_CLASS GameWindow {
private:
    InputInterface *input;
    virtual void SetInputPointer(InputInterface *);
    ...
};
```

This is in my DLL/SO file, and I can access all this. But I cannot access the members of input. Bash crashes withsymbol lookup error:

```
./bin/window.so: undefined symbol: _ZN14InputInterface16SetMouseInWindowEb
```

Does anyone have any ideas about how to resolve this? My input interface class header is included on both sides. The class includes void functions and is not exported (I don't know that it can be. If it needs to be exported, could you please show how?) Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably need a plugin interface.

Comment: The other user, 1201ProgramAlarm, had the write answer, but I'm not really sure what you mean, by that, and, the header of InputInterface was in the executable, the header of which was referenced in both the executable and the dll. Making the functions virtual solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the methods you want to access from the DLL virtual.  Then when you call one the function will be looked up in the vtable (which has been set up in the EXE) and not via an exported symbol name.

This requires that the EXE creates the input objects and passes them to the DLL.  If the DLL needs to create an input object, you'll need to export a factor method from the EXE and dynamically locate it at runtime with LoadLibrary etc.

Comment: Confirming: making each function virtual did, work, thanks!